# ERROR: library `archive' does not exist (SWI-prolog)

Tags: prolog, package, swi-prolog

I'm trying to test out how installing packages works with SWI-prolog, but got this:

```
?- pack_install('https://github.com/propack/app/archive/app-0.0.1.zip').
%  library(ssl) compiled into ssl 0.00 sec, 43 clauses
%    library(rbtrees) compiled into rbtrees 0.01 sec, 190 clauses
%   library(thread_pool) compiled into thread_pool 0.01 sec, 238 clauses
%   http_wrapper compiled into httpd_wrapper 0.00 sec, 68 clauses
%  thread_httpd compiled into thread_httpd 0.02 sec, 407 clauses
% library(http/http_ssl_plugin) compiled into http_ssl_plugin 0.03 sec, 462 clauses

Create directory for packages
   (1) * /Users/lancejpollard/lib/swipl/pack
   (2)   /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/6.6.6/libexec/lib/swipl-6.6.6/pack
   (3)   Cancel

Your choice? 1
ERROR: library `archive' does not exist
   Exception: (10) prolog_pack:pack_archive_info('/Users/lancejpollard/lib/swipl/pack/Downloads/app-0.0.1.zip', app, _G2391, _G2392) ? creep
?-
```

Any ideas? I install swi-prolog via Homebrew, with:

```
brew install swi-prolog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was just to do this:

```
brew install libarchive
brew uninstall swi-prolog
brew install swi-prolog --with-libarchive
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an incomplete installation. In recent SWI-Prolog versions, at least in the current development version, you can check the installation by calling the `check_installation/0` predicate. Note that there are alternative ways to install SWI-Prolog. You seem to be using Mac OS X. If so, you can also install from sources using MacPorts or simply download a Mac OS X disk image with a relocatable application bundle.